# dropzone.js: Only use file drop only with no output

Tags: dropzone.js

I have an existing file upload (manual) in my web application. My application already shows existing uploaded files and a way to delete files.

I would like to incorporate the dropzone.js drag and drop into a small target area - but that is all.  I don't want dropzone to print/render *anything* back to the screen - no messages, no images, nothing.

Could someone provide and example of how to configure dropzone for this limited functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by modifying the stylesheet. For example, setting

```
.dz-details
{
    display:none;
}
```

will remove the box which shows what was uploaded. By modifying more styles, you should be able to remove the other elements that normally appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on init:

```
const dropzoneConfig = {
    addedfile: file => { console.log(file); }
}
const myDropzone = new Dropzone(myDiv, dropzoneConfig)
```